# Qual a diferença de usar função com parâmetro THIS ou OBJ?

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

Fazendo um código JavaScript recentemente, me deparei que ao usar uma function, quando colocava THIS como parâmetro ela não era executada, porém ao colocar OBJ, ela funcionava normalmente. Alguém pode me dizer a diferença entre os dois?

```
function mostraCampo(obj) {
          var select = document.getElementById('instituição')
          if (select.value == 'OUTRA') {
            document.getElementById("outrainst").style.visibility = "visible";
          } else{
            document.getElementById("outrainst").style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
        }
<div class="form-group">                
          <label> Instituição de ensino <br />
            <select class="form-group" name="instituição" id="instituição" onchange="mostraCampo(this.value);">
              <option value="UFTM">UFTM</option>
              <option value="UNIUBE">UNIUBE</option>
              <option value="FACTHUS">FACTHUS</option>
              <option value="SENAI">FAZU</option>
              <option value="IMEPAC">IMEPAC</option>
              <option value="NENHUMA">NENHUMA</option>
              <option value="OUTRA">OUTRA</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="outrainst" id="outrainst" style="visibility: hidden;">
          </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Código PHP ou JavaScript? Aliás, qual código? O que é `this` e o que é `OBJ` nesse exemplo? Por favor, edite sua pergunta e seja mais claro no problema, principalmente adicionando o código que gerou a dúvida.

Comment: Está editado, tinha esquecido de falar que são os parâmetros da function! E eu não sabia como colocar o código.

Comment: Já adiantando: `this` é um objeto que representa o elemento atual, já `obj`, nesse caso, é o argumento da função. São coisas bem distintas. Veja se isso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233628/como-utilizar-o-this-de-maneira-correta

Comment: Acho que entendi, por exemplo, usar o this como eu usei pra chamar a função dentro do select da certo porque ele vai se referir ao select, porém usar como argumento da função ele vai entender o this como uma variável, seria isso?

Comment: Basicamente isso, tanto que nesse caso `obj` será o `this.value` do `select`, então, na função, bastaria você fazer `if (obj == "OUTRA") ...`, sem precisar no `var select`.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, ajudou demais!!!

Answer (score 1):

Bom, se entendi bem sua pergunta é porque o this é reservado pelo parser, então você não pode usar como parametro da função, porque ele pode ser usado dentro dela para setar informações na função. Você pode colocar o nome que quiser na verdade, menos os que estão reservados pelo sistema. Obj é mais uma convenção.

O this serve como exemplo:

```html
function Pessoa(){
  this.idade = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.idade++; // propriedade |this|refere ao objeto pessoa
  }, 1000);
}
```

Então o this está relacionado a quando você quer chamar a própria função em si.
Já o obj é quando você precisa informar um parâmetro na função, por convenção, usa obj, mas podia ser xuxa que ia dar certo. Só não pode ser uma palavra reservada.

Comment: Dê uma encrememtada na resposta, para ela ficar perfeita. E acredito que a pergunta dele é referente a diferença entre THIS e OBJ

Comment: ficou melhor agora, dei até um exemplo prático